# increasing performance on a SELECT query with large 3D point data set

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a large dataset (around 1.9 million rows) of 3D points that I'm selecting from. The statement I use most often is similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM points 
WHERE x > 100 AND x < 200 
AND   y > 100 AND y < 200 
AND   z > 100 AND z < 200 
AND otherParameter > 10
```

I have indicies on x, y, and z as well as the otherParameter. I've also tried adding a multi-part index to x,y,z but that hasn't helped.

Any advice on how to make this `SELECT` query quicker?

Comment: Your using range queries. Indexes are useless. Sometimes you can get it work if you can discretize the values and use the in operator. Like: `where x in (100, 101, ... 200)` This is an excellent article explaining the difference - http://explainextended.com/2009/10/07/in-list-vs-range-condition-mysql/

Comment: Look at nate c's link, my "solution" was incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`B-Tree` indexes won't help much for such a query.

What you need as an `R-Tree` index and the minimal bounding parallelepiped query over it.

Unfortunately, `MySQL` does not support `R-Tree` indexes over `3d` points, only `2d`. However, you may create an index over, say, `X` and `Y` together which will be more selective that any of the `B-Tree` indexes on `X` and `Y` alone:

```
ALTER TABLE points ADD xy POINT;

UPDATE  points
SET     xy = Point(x, y);

ALTER TABLE points MODIFY xy POINT NOT NULL;


CREATE SPATIAL INDEX sx_points_xy ON points (xy);

SELECT  *
FROM    points
WHERE   MBRContains(LineString(Point(100, 100), Point(200, 200), xy)
        AND z BETWEEN 100 and 200
        AND otherParameter > 10;
```

This is only possible if your table is `MyISAM`.

Comment: I need to explore R-Tree. It's interesting, one of the potential solutions I came up with was to add an octree field, assign each row to a node and then pre-process which octrees to select from. This did help speed things up, but when selecting larger volumes, I ran into the same issues due to a large number of tree nodes being selected.

Comment: I'm also interested in which databases DO support 3D R-tree indicies?

Comment: @clexmond: `PostgreSQL` does support custom index types using `GiST` interface. I'm not aware of an out-of-box solution for `3d` types, however, with a little effort it can easily be implemented (if you are familiar with `R-Tree` internals).

Answer (score -1):

I don't have mySQL to test but I'm curious how efficient its INTERSECT is:

```
     select points.*
     from points 
     join 
     ( 
     select id from points where   x > 100 AND x < 200 
     intersect
     select id from points where   y > 100 AND y < 200 
     intersect
     select id from points where   z > 100 AND z < 200 
     ) as keyset
     on points.id = keyset.id
```

Not necessarily recommending this -- but it's something to try, especially if you have separate indexes on x, y, and z.

EDIT: Since mySQl doesn't support INTERSECT the query above could be rewritten using JOINS of inline views. Each view would contain a keyset and each view would have the advantage of the separate indexes you have placed on x, y, and z.  The performance would depend on the numnber of keys returned and on the intersect/join algorithm.

I first tested the intersect approach (in SQLite) to see if there were ways to improve performance in spatial queries short of using their R-Tree module.  INTERSECT was actually slower than using a single non-composite index on one of the spatial values and then scanning the subset of the base table to get the other spatial values. But the results can vary depending on the size of the database. After the table has reached gargantuan size and disk i/o becomes more important as a performance factor, it may be more efficient to intersect discrete keysets, each of which has been instantiated from an index, than to do a scan of the base table subequent to an initial fetch-from-index.

Comment: `MySQL` does not support `INTERSECT`.

Comment: Let's deduct a point from mySQL while we're at it, for not supporting INTERSECT.

Comment: Does it support INNER JOINS on inline views?