# MySQL - How to improve a table with 50 million rows?

Tags: mysql

All-

So I have a table which has 56 million rows, and inserting data and querying it is taking a VERY VERY long time. I'm curious of any recommendations people may have.

My server has 32GB of RAM (most not used), 2X RAID SSDs, and an E3-1270, so it should be quite quick.

Yet some select queries are taking upwards of 40 seconds. I basically store positions of objects in a game world.  Here is the structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `object_positions2` (
  `entry` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `x_int` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `y_int` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `z_int` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `x` float NOT NULL,
  `y` float NOT NULL,
  `z` float NOT NULL,
  `continent` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `zone` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `build` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entry`,`type`,`x_int`,`y_int`,`z_int`),
  KEY `entry` (`entry`,`type`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I query based on entry and type (which is why there is an index there), and I round the float x,y,z to an int on insertion (as a more efficient way to NOT insert if it already exists since float comparisons are expensive).

Does anyone have any ideas as to why it's taking so long to do inserts or even queries? Does MySQL not support this many rows?

Here is the example insert statement:

```
REPLACE INTO `object_positions2` (`entry` ,`type` , `x_int` , `y_int` , `z_int`, `x` ,`y` ,`z` ,`continent` ,`zone` ,`build`) VALUES ('$entry', '$type', '" . round($x) . "', '" . round($y) . "', '" . round($z) . "', '$x', '$y', '$z', '$continent', '$zone', '$ZeBuild');
```

Thanks in advance!
~ Josh

Comment: basic rule of thumb: **ANY** field used in a `join`, `where`, or `order by` clause should have an index on it. that means you need an index on npc_flags, but you're also doing where on a DERIVED value of that field,w hich means indexes CAN'T be used. ditto with the sqrt/pow stuff.

Comment: whatch the 3d/2d indexes of mysql
solved on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974299/increasing-performance-on-a-select-query-with-large-3d-point-data-set

Answer (score 1):

Adding index on some of your columns (on dose you use them in joins and in where condition) will help you on query

Comment: That did it for the select thanks!  Any ideas on the insert/replace into?

Comment: @Geesu for sure. If the column you use in where clause is not the primary key (witch have an index) then index will improve your query speed

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing spatial data you may consider using a spatial database. According to the wikipedia page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database)  there is a spatial package available for mysql, though I have only used oracle and postgis myself.

At the very least, I advise against storing vertices as rows, and instead store the geometries indexed by their MBR.

If I had to guess, I suspect the composite primary key on entry,type,x,y and z is what is slowing your queries and updates, especially for 56 million rows where there may be a lot of duplicates for these values.

Comment: It's only x, y, not Z.  So I can't use that :/

Comment: Both Oracle and PostGIS support 2,3 and 4 dimensional indexes - I am not sure about the MySql extension.

Even when simply using x and y for 56 million rows, think about the work the database has to do with a non spatial index : it gets all values matching the x condition using an index of the x value, and then check the y criteria for each of these rows. (Which may be a massive number of rows.) Using something like an RTree (Spatial index) filters these far more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

The `entry` key is useless, since the data is already in your primary key. I would add an autoinrement id for primary key (changing the current primary key to unique index), convert table to InnoDB (it provides much  better concurrency) and set large enough innodb_buffer_pool_size. If you must use MyISAM, check `key_buffer_size` setting